# Should I remove "Commerce Base" from site before an upgrade?

Tags: commerce, composer, 9, distributions, upgrading

The "Upgrade Status" module reports that "**Commerce Base**" exists in site file structure, but is not installed and suggests removing it. I expect that the Commerce project references those files to work, but I don't know.

**Should this project in my composer/json 'requires' list be removed using Composer?**
"drupalcommerce/commerce_base": "dev-8.x-1.x",

[image: Remove listing in Upgrade Status module report]

My original Drupal 8 install was with Composer using:
`composer create-project drupalcommerce/project-base XXXXXX --stability dev`

I presently have Commerce 8.x-2.26 installed.

I'd like to upgrade to from Drupal 8.9.x to 9.2.x.

Thank you for any advice!

Comment: It's used by the project-base package, so probably listed directly in your own composer.json? If so and it's uninstalled, should be safe to remove

Comment: I tried to remove drupalcommerce/commerce_base project but then get a white screen of death when vistiing a commerce page : The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

So I think I need to get a newer version of commerce_base ?

Answer (score 1):

There was a bug in upgrade_status that didn't treat profiles (like drupalcommerce/project-base ) as they should be. But instead treated it like a misbehaving module.

This is fixed in this issue: https://www.drupal.org/project/upgrade_status/issues/3230266

So you can try the patch from that issue, or wait for a new release which includes the patch.